# Why is looping through a Devices object not returning Device objects?

Tags: rust, audio, error-handling, iteration

I'm trying to Rust's [cpal](https://docs.rs/cpal/) crate to enumerate a system's default host audio devices with the following code:

```
use cpal::traits::{HostTrait, DeviceTrait};
use cpal::{Device, Host};

fn main(){
    let default_host:Host = cpal::default_host();
    for device in default_host.devices().into_iter(){
        println!("> {}", device.name())
    }
}
```

When I run the code it becomes apparent that the objects I'm iterating through aren't `Device` objects but `Devices` objects, returning the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `name` found for struct `Devices` in the current scope

   |
16 |         println!("> {}", device.name())
   |                                 ^^^^ method not found in `Devices`
```

Not sure where to go from here, I've read the relevant cpal and rust documentation repeatedly but I think I'm missing something very fundamental. Any idea what that might be?

Comment: Note that `into_iter()` is redundant, `for` does that automatically.

Comment: Please don't include the solution in the question. Instead you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not sure where to go from here, I've read the relevant cpal and rust documentation repeatedly but I think I'm missing something very fundamental. Any idea what that might be?

[`HostTrait::Devices`](https://docs.rs/cpal/latest/cpal/traits/trait.HostTrait.html#tymethod.devices) can apparently fail so it returns a

```
Result<Self::Devices, DevicesError>
```

Results, like options, [are iterable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/result/enum.Result.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-Result%3CT,+E%3E), when iterated they behave as a sequence of 0 (Err) or 1 (Ok) items. That is what your `into_iter()` invokes, it iterates the result, rather than the devices inside the result.

Comment: There is a rustc warning about that, but it is silenced twice because: (a) the explicit `into_iter()`, (b) the error.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

As @Masklinn noted, default_host.devices() actually returns a `Result` object, not a `Devices` object. I handled the `Result` using pattern matching and had each arm of the match call a different function. One panics in case of error, and one progresses the flow of logic if it returns successfully:

```
use cpal::traits::{HostTrait, DeviceTrait};
use cpal::{Device, Host};

fn main() {
    let default_host:Host = cpal::default_host();
    match default_host.devices() {
        Ok(devices) => print_devices(devices),
        Err(_error) => panic!("Error retrieving devices"),
    }; }

fn print_devices(default_host_devices: cpal::Devices) {
    for device in default_host_devices {
        println!("> {}", device.name().unwrap())
    } }
```

In the future I'll write a more robust version that doesn't panic upon failing to enumerate the host devices but for now this is fine. @Chayim Friedman also correctly noted that for loops call `.to_iter()` on objects automatically, so I removed the explicit `.to_iter()` from my print_devices function.